# foreach() error when using wordpress wp_get_sidebars_widgets()

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

```
function getWidgets($position = null) {
    if (empty($this->widgets)) {
        foreach (wp_get_sidebars_widgets() as $pos => $ids) {
            $this->widgets[$pos] = array();
            foreach ($ids as $id) {                  // error is here
                $this->widgets[$pos][$id] = $this->getWidget($id);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

These are lines 305-314.

I'm getting this error:

```
" Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/content/73/9889573/html/wp-content/themes/yoo_spark_wp/warp/systems/wordpress.3.0/helpers/system.php on line 310 "
```

Can someone tell me how do i fix it

Comment: Your line numbers are a little off, because line 310 is `$this->widgets[$pos][$id] = $this->getWidget($id);` but the error refers to the argument in the foreach loop.

Answer (score 2):

`wp_get_sidebars_widgets()` returns a 1-dimensional array.

**Reference**: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_sidebars_widgets

`$ids` is not an array. You cannot traverse it in a `foreach` loop.

Try this:

```
$widgets = array();
foreach (wp_get_sidebars_widgets() as $pos => $id) {
    $widgets[$pos] = $this->getWidget($id);
}
```

Comment: so what do I put .. im lost when it comes to .php

Comment: did that and got this " Warning: Illegal offset type in isset or empty in /home/content/73/9889573/html/wp-content/themes/yoo_spark_wp/warp/systems/wordpress.3.0/helpers/system.php on line 255   "